# RavenDB Index no longer returning results

Tags: ravendb

I'm attempting to apply Ayende's order search from [here](http://ayende.com/blog/152833/orders-search-in-ravendb) to an existing index.

The current index looks like this:

```
public class HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2 : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MPDocument, HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Constituency { get; set; }
        public decimal? AmountPaid { get; set; }
    }

    public HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2()
    {
        Map = mps => from mp in mps
                        from exp in mp.Expenses
                        select new
                        {
                            mp.Name,
                            mp.Constituency,
                            exp.AmountPaid
                        };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by new { result.Name, result.Constituency } into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Name = g.Key.Name,
                                Constituency = g.Key.Constituency,
                                AmountPaid = g.Sum(x => x.AmountPaid)
                            };

        Index(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x => x.Constituency, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

This index works fine. However when I try to change the Map to:

```
from mp in mps
from exp in mp.Expenses
select new
{
    Query = new object[]{mp.Name,mp.Constituency},
    mp.Name,
    mp.Constituency,
    exp.AmountPaid
};
```

and the reduce to

```
from result in results
group result by new { result.Name, result.Constituency } into g
select new
{
    Query = "",
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    Constituency = g.Key.Constituency,
    AmountPaid = g.Sum(x => x.AmountPaid)
};
```

I then get no results when querying on the `Query` property. If I remove the reduce the index returns data, but it always returns the full `MPDocument`, which is much more that I was to materialise. Is there a way to use the technique described in the original post that also utilises a reduce?

Comment: In your Reduce statement you've set the Query to an empty string, is this corrent? If so the only query that would match it is an empty string!!

Comment: When you have an index with a Reduce section, you query against the output of the Reduce part, not the Map part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your reduce function:

```
Query = g.Select(x => x.Query).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault()
```

In order to query on that field, you need to have a seperate query model and a result model. Here is a full example using your code:

```
public class MultiTermFieldInMapReduce
{
    public class MPDocument
    {
        public List<Epense> Expenses { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Constituency { get; set; }

        public class Epense
        {
            public decimal? AmountPaid { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2 : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MPDocument, HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2.ReduceResult>
    {
        public class ReduceResult
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Constituency { get; set; }
            public decimal? AmountPaid { get; set; }
            public object[] Query { get; set; }
        }

        public class SearchModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Constituency { get; set; }
            public decimal? AmountPaid { get; set; }
            public string Query { get; set; }
        }

        public HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2()
        {
            Map = mps => from mp in mps
                         from exp in mp.Expenses
                         select new
                         {
                             mp.Name,
                             mp.Constituency,
                             exp.AmountPaid,
                             Query = new object[]
                             {
                                 mp.Name,
                                 mp.Constituency
                             }
                         };

            Reduce = results => from result in results
                                group result by new { result.Name, result.Constituency } into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    Name = g.Key.Name,
                                    Constituency = g.Key.Constituency,
                                    AmountPaid = g.Sum(x => x.AmountPaid),
                                    Query = g.Select(x => x.Query).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault()
                                };

            Index(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
            Index(x => x.Constituency, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Query_returns_results()
    {
        using (var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true }.Initialize())
        {
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(new MapReduceError.MPDocument
                {
                    Name = "test1",
                    Expenses = new List<MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense>
                    {
                        new MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense {AmountPaid = 5.5m},
                        new MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense {AmountPaid = 5.5m},
                        new MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense {AmountPaid = 5.5m},
                        new MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense {AmountPaid = 5.5m}
                    }
                });

                session.Store(new MapReduceError.MPDocument
                {
                    Name = "test2",
                    Expenses = new List<MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense>
                    {
                        new MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense {AmountPaid = 10},
                        new MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense {AmountPaid = 10},
                        new MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense {AmountPaid = 10},
                        new MapReduceError.MPDocument.Epense {AmountPaid = 10}
                    }
                });

                session.SaveChanges();
            }

            new HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2().Execute(store);

            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                var results =
                    session.Query
                        <HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2.SearchModel, HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2>()
                        .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
                        .Where(x => x.Query == "test1")
                        .As<HomeBlurb_IncludeTotalCosts_Search2.ReduceResult>()
                        .ToList();

                Assert.Equal(1, results.Count);
                Assert.Equal(22, results.First().AmountPaid);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a Map/Reduce index to do this, you seem to only be reducing on MPDocument Name and Constituency, which I guess are unique to each MP.

I think that you want to use TransformResults, so that you can change the shape of the output instead, something like so:

```
 TransformResults =
            (database, mps) => from mp in mps
                                 select new 
                                 {
                                     mp.Name,
                                     mp.???
                                     < JUST THE BITS YOU WANT RETURNED >
                                 };
```

Then you query like so:

```
session.Query<mp>("index name")
        .Where(..)
        .As<MPQueryResult>()
        .ToList()
```